# Find the Record with Null Values and Display the Column Names using Unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have following Input file and need to find which field has null and Display the Key Column and Null Value Column Name.

Note : In Future There might be New Fields can be added too.

Input.txt

```
Keyfeild1|Over|Loan|cc|backup
200|12||0|
100||15|1|200
100|100|100|100|100
50||50||11
```

ExpectedOutput.txt :

```
200|Loan
200|backup
100|Over
50|Over
50|cc
```

Command Used :

```
cat Input.txt | awk -F"|" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="") { print $1"|"i} }'
```

Achieved Output:

```
200|3
200|5
100|2
50|2
50|4
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, a little tweak needed in your code, added it.

Comment: Please do not post same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F"|"  'FNR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i==""){print $1,"field"i}}}' OFS="|"  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
200|field3
200|field5
100|field2
50|field2
50|field4
```